# Multilanguage site using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a multi-language site using ReactJS. My main JS component is as follows:

```
    var React = require('react');
var Header = require('../common/header');
var HeaderCompact = require('../common/headerCompact');
var Footer = require('../common/footer');


var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            lang: 1
        };
    },

    changeLang: function(name, event){

        switch (name){
            case "fra" :
                this.setState({lang: 2});
                break;
            case "ger" :
                this.setState({lang: 3});
                break;
            case "ned" :
                this.setState({lang: 4});
                break;
            default:
                this.setState({lang: 1});
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        var currentRoute = this.props.location.pathname.slice(1);
        var header = currentRoute === "" ? <Header onClick={this.changeLang} lang={this.state.lang}/> : <HeaderCompact currentRoute={currentRoute} onClick={this.changeLang} lang={this.state.lang}/>;
        return (
            <div>
                {header}
                {this.props.children}
                <Footer lang={this.state.lang}/>
            </div>

        );
    }
});

module.exports = App;
```

My header component is as follows:

```
    'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var Link = require('react-router').Link;
var FontAwesome = require('react-fontawesome');

var Header = React.createClass({


    render: function () {
        var lang = this.props.lang;
        console.log("State je : " + lang);
        var language = "";
        switch (lang){
            case 1 :
                language = require('./en');
                var hideEng = "hideEng";
                break;
            case 2 :
                language = require('./fr');
                var hideFra = "hideFra";
                break;
            case 3 :
                language = require('./de');
                var hideGer = "hideGer";
                break;
            default:
                language = require('./nl');
                var hideNed = "hideNed";
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="sub-header">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 headerLogo noPadding">
                                <Link to="/">
                                    <img src="../images/logos/logo-header-compact.png" style={{paddingTop: 10}}/>
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 noPadding">
                                <ul className="langAndBtn">
                                    <li className="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style={{paddingTop: 20}}>
                                        <Link to="/" className={hideNed} style={{marginRight: 5}} onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this, 'ned')}><img src="../images/languages/nl.png" /></Link>
                                        <Link to="/" className={hideEng} style={{marginRight: 5}} onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this, 'eng')}><img src="../images/languages/gb.png" /></Link>
                                        <Link to="/" className={hideFra} style={{marginRight: 5}} onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this, 'fra')}><img src="../images/languages/fr.png" /></Link>
                                        <Link to="/" className={hideGer} onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this, 'ger')}><img src="../images/languages/ger.png" /></Link>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 text-center">
                                        <div className="advanced-button text-center" style={{width: 215, margin: '0 auto'}}>
                                            <Link to="registration" className="btnRegistrationHeader text-center" title="">
                                                <span className="regHeaderText">{language.homePage.registrationButton}</span>
                                                <FontAwesome name="user" className="faIcon" style={{borderLeft: '1px solid #a0acb8', borderTop: '1px solid #a0acb8', borderBottom: '1px solid #a0acb8'}}/>
                                            </Link>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div className="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="container pageTitle" style={{margin: '30px auto 0 !important', textAlign: 'center !important'}}>
                    <div className="homeTitle">{language.homePage.title}</div>
                    <div className="homeSubtitle">{language.homePage.subtitle}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Header;
```

And that works without problems. But this way, translation works only for the header and footer. How can I pass **lang={this.state.lang}** to the router (this.props.children) inside the render method of my App component so that I can do the translation on the home page too?

Comment: That's why we need some library like `redux` and `flux`, manage these state is doable, but cumbersome.

Comment: You can check this project https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl.  
You can also use react context to solve this https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Comment: I personally prefer to keep this out of react using i18n-js in my rails projects. I took a look at react-intl and it looks like an extremely consulted way of doing the same.